# Проблема с отображением символов в mysql

Tags: mysql, vkontakte-api

Пишу бота ВК на python. Использую mysql. Когда например мне надо записать ник пользователя, а они часто в нике указывают эмодзи. Когда я их записываю за место эмодзи возникает "?". Подозреваю что проблема с кодировкой, но как её поменять я так и не понял. Сразу говорю что доступа к phpmyadmin у меня нет "такие правила хоста".

Comment: Базу в юникод, таблицу, столбцы, файлы принимать в юникоде.

Comment: Так это я понял. А какие команды в консоль писать?